# Return Cells reference from a VBA Class

Tags: vba, excel, class

I have an Excel VBA Procedure to create a data-table. To simplify the code I want to create a `BreakDownTable` class.

When I’m trying to run the code I get Run-time error:

> 424 – Object required.

Any idea how to get the Cells reference from the Class?

```
Private sub CreateTable()
Dim bdTable As New BreakDownTable
bdTable.StartingPosition = Range(refEditTabel.value)
bdTable.Cell(0, 0) = "Key"
bdTable.Cell(0, 1) = "Summary”

Dim dateRange as Range
Set dateRange = Range(bdTable.Cell(2, 3), bdTable.Cell(7, 6)
…
End sub
```

BreakDownTable CLASS:

```
Private pStartingPosition As Range

Public Property Get StartingPosition() As Range
    StartingPosition = pStartingPosition
End Property

Public Property Let StartingPosition(value As Range)
    Set pStartingPosition = value
End Property

Public Function Cell(row As Integer, col As Integer)
    Cell = Cells(pStartingPosition.row + row, pStartingPosition.Column + col)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing a `set` when you assign `Cell` to an object reference:

```
Set Cell = Cells(pStartingPosition.row + row, pStartingPosition.Column + col)
```